# How to find the difference between two columns using LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two data tables and would like to join the two tables to find the difference between the two columns, however it keeps returning null and erroring out at CopyToDataTable method as you cannot pass null into it. I have checked just before this code that there are exactly same data in TestOutput and ExpectedOutput tables.
Here's my code:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> diff =
  (from datarows1 in TestOutput.AsEnumerable()
   join datarows2 in ExpectedOutput.AsEnumerable() 
   on datarows1.Field<String>("external_id") equals datarows2.Field<String>("external_id")

   select new
   {
      KeyId = datarows1.Field<String>("external_id"),
      Difference = datarows1.Field<Decimal>("quantity") - datarows2.Field<Decimal>("quantity")
    }) as IEnumerable<DataRow>;

DataTable difference = diff.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Error Message @ last row:

> ArgumentNullException was unhandled - value cannot be null. Parameter name:source

Comment: Posting exact error message (rather than you paraphrasing it) is nice.  Some people have the whole list memorized, but most of us don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `as IEnumerable<DataRow>`cast. If you remove that line you will see that your query is selecting out an anonymous type with properties `KeyID` and `Difference`, **not** an IEnumerable. The `as` operator attempts to cast `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and returns a `null` if no such cast is possible. That is where your null reference exception is coming from.

To fix this, you need to find a different technique of populating the DataTable from your `IEnumerable<a'>` (where `a'` is the anonymous type)

```
DataTable difference = new DataTable();
difference.Columns.Add("KeyID", typeof(string));
difference.Columns.Add("Difference", typeof(decimal));

foreach (var result in diff)
   difference.Rows.Add(result.KeyID, result.Difference);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you do:

`select new {...}`

you are creating an anonymous class, not a DataRow. Hence when you cast it `as IEnumerable<DataRow>` it becomes `null`

If you use an implicitly typed variable:

```
 var diff = 
  (from datarows1 in TestOutput.AsEnumerable() 
   join datarows2 in ExpectedOutput.AsEnumerable()  
   on datarows1.Field<String>("external_id") equals datarows2.Field<String>("external_id") 

   select new 
   { 
      KeyId = datarows1.Field<String>("external_id"), 
      Difference = datarows1.Field<Decimal>("quantity") - datarows2.Field<Decimal>("quantity") 
    });
```

That will create a diff of the correct type.

Comment: He'll also need to remove the generic parameter to `CopyToDataTable`.  Just not having it at all and letting the compiler supply it will be fine.

Comment: Would you describe what's a difference between your current code and OPs code? you just eliminate casting but this wont works either.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri He eliminated an illegal cast.  Because the cast always failed the code never worked.  Rather than using a cast that can't ever succeed, the appropriate thing to do is change the variable to what the query actually returns.

Comment: @Servy, check OPs last line: `DataTable difference = diff.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();`, means OP wants to copy them into another DataTable, sure it wasn't hard for OP to eliminate illegal cast, obviously OP used cast for `CopyToDataTable`.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri [CopyToDataTable need not be called on just `DataRow` elements.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx).  It can be used to turn an enumeration of anonymous types into a DataTable just fine.

Comment: @Servy, I'd offer you read the article then link it (at least read this part : "only operate on an IEnumerable source where the generic parameter T is of type DataRow."), msdn documentation explicitly says this, I don't know what you read, please let me know if you understand any magic, the code in msdn documentation explicitly explains how to write a `custom extended method for CopyToDataTable` not about .net's default functionality.

Comment: actually, you guys are right. I'm having trouble storing the result of the linq query into a DataTable. I thought using the previous post solved it, but for some reason - it wouldn't enter the foreach loop. Is there any other way to store it into a DataTable?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Of course I've read it.  I've also used it on a number of occasions.  The use of the two methods is indistinguishable unless using are included, although I agree it is implied.  I would assert that the best solution, is to use the extension in the article that I linked.  Clearly that's the intent of the OP at least.

Comment: @user1639184, my answer could help you and it's simplest possible way to do this.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Simplest?  It may or may not be helpful, but it is most certainly not the simplest.  pickles' answer is the simplest.

Comment: @Servy, in my opinion, the way in msdn article is not the best way (because of huge amount of reflection they used), sure it's slower than my way also it uses more memory, but I think we could agree that, this answer, is not the answer that OP wants, and my answer is the only correct one. I just see your comment,  pickles answer is not manageable and extensible, with new field you should change the code, so it's not simple.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri We most certainly cannot agree on either point.  As to whether the code has performance issues is contextual.  While it does have some overhead at runtime, it provides an *enourmous* convenience on the programmer to not need to deal with setting up the DataTable schema, or build custom objects.  That often makes it more than worth the cost, especially because most of that cost is per query/table, not per row.  Your answer is also most certainly not the **only** correct one.  It may or may not be workable, but the two other posted answers demonstrate other possible routes.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri You say adding another field makes pickles' solution unworkable, and yet every single one of the three solutions here would need to be re-worked if a new field was added.  In fact, using the method I've proposed would require the least work, and yours would require the most (adding a new field to a custom class plus populating it in the query).

Comment: @Servy, I think you understand Nick Jones's answer is not enough, but you can't accept your fault. and about pickles's answer all noob programmers can understand the manageability of that code is harder than mine, but if you don't like accept this I can't explain it, it's too clear and I can't expect a user with 9K rep needs explanation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16107/discussion-between-servy-and-saeed-amiri)

Answer (score 0):

You used anonymous types in your `select new` instead of this you should use some type which inherits from `DataRow` like your current table types:

```
.....
select new MyDataType
{
   external_id= datarows1.Field<String>("external_id"),
   quantity = datarows1.Field<Decimal>("quantity") 
              - datarows2.Field<Decimal>("quantity")
}) .ToList();

DataTable difference = diff.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Actually your cast is not valid, and it'll be converted to null.

Comment: It's not really practical to create a new type that extends `DataRow` just to execute this query.  `DataRow` isn't really designed to be extended.  There's also no need to convert a query to a list when you're only going to execute `IEnumerable` function on it.  Why go through extra overhead of making a list just to disregard that list?

Comment: @Servy, List overhead compare to IEnumerable is eligible and I like to use list, and this doesn't changes anything, also OP tried to copy the result in the similar table, and if has a good design there is no need to create a class, he could use his previous classes.

Comment: Using a `List` forces all of the data to be pulled into memory, rather than allowing it to be streamed.  If there are a lot of rows this could potentially add up to a lot of memory being used (and a lot of extra work for the GC to clean it up) all for literally 0 gains.  If you were using some `List` functionallity then you could at least argue the point, but as is there are a handful of small negatives an no positives.  As for creating the class, even if he has a data holder class for this data it almost certainly doesn't extend `DataRow` (nor should it).

Comment: @Servy, when OP finally want have a data in DataTable, this forces OP to fetch it in memory, so first fetch doesn't changes anything, also why I wrote ToList, because in my opinion it's more readable and doesn't have any significant performance issue, also it was possible (by my code), to use it directly, I just tried to show to OP, he don't need explicit casting to do this. Also about creating class, in my opinion, in situation like this, this is the best way, if you have another opinion, we could discuss in chat. anyway if you downvote this, I'd offer change your vote direction.

Comment: Yes, you will be forced to pull the entire query into memory when you copy it to a DataTable.  That doesn't excuse copying it twice, one to a list, and again to a datatable.  You say it changes nothing, but that's not true, it uses up extra memory, and spends time and effort allocationg/cleaning up that memory in order to accomplish exactly nothing.  In what way is it more readable to use a List than an `IEnumerable` in this case?  How does it demonstrate that he doesn't need explicit casting?  (Just removing the cast does that.)

Comment: As for the new class, as I've said, it would be just fine to use a custom class as a data holder as opposed to an anonymous type, but that class almost certainly doesn't, and shouldn't implement `DataRow`.  It's contrary to the design of data rows and data tables for you to do that, not to mention a whole lot of extra work that you need to do just right.  Additionally, were I to have downvoted this, do you really think I would change my vote just because you told me not to in the face of all of the problems with it *that I have told you* that you haven't adequately refuted?